# How do I sorting a 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I've got the following array of arrays:

```
array([[ 0.04497471, -3.        ],
       [ 0.0449076 , -2.        ],
       [ 0.0448405 , -1.        ],
       [ 0.04463641,  1.        ],
       [ 0.0445693 ,  2.        ],
       [ 0.04450219,  3.        ]])
```

(this example is already sorted)

I want to sort it so the first column is ordered in descending order, while maintaining the figure in the second column with its partner.

I've tried using `np.sort(a, axis=0)`, but it treats the columns separately. How do I get it to maintain the rows?

Comment: `a[a[:,0].argsort()[::-1]]`? Or `a[(-a[:,0]).argsort()]`?

Comment: That's the right answer- thank you!